# How to organize my casperjs script

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, code-organization

My current script looks like this (pseudo code):

```
casper.start(some_sample_url, function(){
    a_list_of_data = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent())

    for(var i = 0; i < a_list_of_data.length; i++){
        entry = a_list_of_data[i];
        entry_url = entry.get_url();
        result = __utils__.sendAJAX(entry_url, "POST", {some: "data"}, false, {some: "option"});
        casper.download(result, ...);
    }
});
casper.run();
```

I've learned that `__utils__.sendAJAX` should be put in a `this.evaluate` which in turn should be in a `casper.then`. However, after I change my code to that form it seems all the `POST` requests simply not sent out. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The only constraint is that `__utils__` is only defined/injected in/into page context (inside of `casper.evaluate`). So you simply cannot use it outside. Since passing `false` as a third argument to `__utils__.sendAJAX` makes it a blocking call, you can use it in your script.

```
for(var i = 0; i < a_list_of_data.length; i++){
    entry = a_list_of_data[i];
    entry_url = entry.get_url();
    result = this.evaluate(function(){
        return __utils__.sendAJAX(entry_url, "POST", {some: "data"}, false, {some: "option"});
    });
    casper.download(result, ...);
}
```

Note that `casper.download` is arbitrarily limited to 30 second downloads (hard limit) and only a few megabyte of data. It actually uses `__utils__.sendAJAX` behind the scenes.

If you expect binary data, you will need to encode the string before returning it from the page context and decoding it in casper context.

---

All `casper.then*` and `casper.wait*` functions create a step that will be added to the step queue and executed one after the other. Some functions also create steps such as `casper.repeat`, `casper.start`, `casper.run` and others. If there is a callback function named `then` or `onTimeout`, it is a step.

All code that you want to be executed needs to be in at least one step function otherwise it will be executed outside of the control flow. There are strategies to catch up with a broken off control flow. But none of this is needed here.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking about *code-organization*, since this is quite the small example that is easily solved.